# Run skipped python tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to run all unittests in a module, including the skipped ones, from the command line, without using a test runner like `nose` etc. 
Currently I have `python3 -m unittest discover`, but I don't see any option to override skipped tests. Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/unittest/main.py#l48) for the command line utility there doesn't seem to be a sane way to avoid the skipping. A nasty workaround would be to monkey-patch `skip` before discovering tests:

```
python -c "import unittest as u; u.skip = lambda r: lambda t: t; u.main(None, argv=['', 'discover'])"
```

(Possibly also patch `unittest.case.skip`; this is not at all guaranteed to work as it relies on how the decorator is usually used, but you'll see whether anything still has been skipped.)

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm surprised this doesn't exist as a command line argument. Maybe I will submit a PR..